# Problema de permiso SqlTableDependency con el grupo de Active Directory

Tags: c#, sql-server

Implementé [SqlTableDependency](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SqlTableDependency/) en `C#`. Todo funcionaba bien con el ID de usuario individual, que se otorgó como `db_owner`, pero me dijeron que los ID individuales no pueden crear en el entorno de QA/PROD y que deben usar el inicio de sesión del ActiveDirectory 'Dominio/AD_GP_NAME'.

Luego me asignan a este grupo y este grupo tampoco tiene permitido establecer el propietario de db. Este grupo se agrega como inicio de sesión en SQL DB. Desde el código C# estoy usando `'Integerated security = SSPI'` en la cadena de conexión y al ejecutar SQL Profiler en lugar de dominio `\AD_GP_Name`, muestra mi ID de Windows y en `_dependency.start()`

Recibo el siguiente error:

> **Una entidad de tipo servicio no puede ser propiedad de un rol, un grupo o entidades principales asignadas a certificados o claves asimétricas**

Intenté varios enlaces de ayuda, como verificar el esquema asignado a este grupo que es `dbo`. También se verificó al asignar el

```
GRANT CREATE QUEUE to [domain\AD_GP_Name]
GRANT CREATE SERVICE to [domain\AD_GP_Name]

GRANT SELECT to [domain\AD_GP_Name] 
GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO [domain\AD_GP_Name] 
GRANT RECEIVE ON QueryNotificationErrorsQueue TO [domain\AD_GP_Name] 

GRANT REFERENCES on 
CONTRACT::[http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification]
  to [domain\AD_GP_Name] 
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO [domain\AD_GP_Name]
```

pero ninguna de esta soluciones resolvió el problema.